# Spring boot multiple project, thymeleaf with html template, cannot find template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, build.gradle

Building the SDK, have a microservice for demo. Only need to have spring mvc in src/demo.
When render the index.html which is localhost:8080, it always shows

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Apr 13 00:44:42 PDT 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

The structure of my project

```
src
  \__demo
    \__ java
      \__ com
        \__ example
          \__ Demo.java
          \__ DemoController.java
    \__ resources
      \__templates
        \__ index.html
      \__application.properties 
    \__build.gradle

  \__main
    \__ java
      \__ com
        \__ example
          \__Application.java
    \__build.gradle
```

//In Demo.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        SpringApplication.run(Demo.class, args);
    }
}
```

//In DemoController.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class DemoController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

//In resources/templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title> Thymeleaf Spring Boot Demo </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Welcome to Thymeleaf Demo In Spring Boot</h4>
    </body>
</html>
```

//In application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

//In build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "application"
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'

group 'com.example'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('java')
    }
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['java']

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.json:json:20201115'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile project(':main')
}

application {
    mainClassName = "com.example.Demo"
}

task runWithJavaExec(type: JavaExec) {
    group = "Execution"
    description = "Run the main class with JavaExecTask"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "com.example.Demo"
}
```

//Error code

```
2021-04-13 01:07:36.492 ERROR 11818 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [index], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [index], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1393) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1138) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1077) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Your project structure is wrong. The path for templates in your project should be `src/main/resources/tempaltes` not `src/resources/templates`. Hence it isn't on the classpath hence it isn't found. The same for your `src/demo` folder with java classes that isn't on the classpath either.

Comment: @M.Deinum,  Sorry for the bad path structure, but the path is `src/demo/resources/templates`. The thing is, the main project is our sdk service. The micorservice , which is demo is the spring boot server where I want to render the mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your build.gradle file try to replace:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['java']
```

with

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
          srcDir 'src/main/java'
          srcDir 'src/demo/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/demo/resources' 
        }
    }
}
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

`src/demo` is not a standard gradle path for java resources.
Correct standard path is `src/main`
Gradle didn't compile your files in `src/demo`, so your compiled project can't find them.

Correct project structure should be:

```
src
  \__main
    \__ java
      \__ com
        \__ example
          \__ Demo.java
          \__ DemoController.java
          \__Application.java
    \__ resources
      \__templates
        \__ index.html
      \__application.properties 
    \__build.gradle
```

P.S. if you need to split files in separate "demo" and "main" folders you have to create 2 projects and add one project as a dependency of the other. If you need information how to do it, you need to create separate question. In any case, I would start with one project first.

Comment: The thing is, the main project is our sdk service which should located in main folder. The micorservice, demo is the spring boot server where I want to render the mvc for testing the sdk. I know how to depend one project on another. that's what I'm doing now. Is it possilbe to redefine the path somehow to let the sping boot to check the `demo` folder instead of `main` folder for searching the template?

Comment: The problem is that almost all your files are in src/demo folder and completely ignored by gradle during compile. They actually don't "exist" for gradle, so even if you successfully load template there will be other exceptions.